# The method fillArc paint the arcs with wrong dimensions

Tags: java, graphics

I have a problem with the method fillArc of the class Graphics.

When I give the int values of the size of the arc,it paint an arc with wrong dimensions.

```
 Dimension dimensione;  //dimension of the window. 
 public void paint() {

    BufferStrategy bS = this.getBufferStrategy();

    Graphics g=bS.getDrawGraphics();
   g.clearRect(0, 0,(int)dimensione.getWidth(), (int)dimensione.getHeight());



   // g.fillArc((int)dimensione.getWidth()/2-150,(int)dimensione.getHeight()/2-150, 300,300, 0, 360);
        g.fillArc(0,0,(int)dimensione.getWidth(), (int)dimensione.getHeight(),0, 360);


    bS.show();


    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Disegno.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

It should create an arc as big as the window... but this is the result:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are the dimensions you are using and what is the size of you viewable area - it’s more likely your window is to small

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understand that the “viewable area” is the window size MINUS the frame decorations.

You shouldn’t be using the window size as a baseline, instead, override `getPreferredSize` (in your case of `java.awt.Canvas`) and return the preferred size you would like to use, you can then use `Window#pack` to pack the window around the content and it will become platform independent.

You can then use the `getWidth` and `getHeight` methods of `Canvas` to determine the actual size available